# Function_score query with filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to consider the priority of the company in the search result. The documentation has a similar "Boosting Filtered Subsetsedit" option. In the result, I get this json request and get an error. Perhaps I'm not in the same sequence I put a request for filtering. Tell me in what order it is necessary to write a question considering the filtering.

```
{
"index":"base",
"type":"info",
"from":0,
"size":10,
"fields":["cID","firm_html"],
"body":
       {
        "query":
                {
                "bool":
                      {
                       "must_not":[
                                  {
                                  "match":
                                         {
                                        "info.published":"no"
                                         }
                                  }
                                  ],
                       "should":[
                                {
                                "query_string":
                                               {
                                                "default_field":
                                                    "info.shortname",
                                                    "query":"value"
                                                }
                                },
                                {
                                "match":
                                        {
                                        "_all":"value"
                                        }
                                },
                                ]
                       },
                "function_score":
                                {
                                "functions":[
                                            {
                                            "filter":
                                                     {
                                                 "term":
                                                        {
                                                         "razm_prio":"0.4"
                                                        }
                                                 },
                                            "weight":"0.4"
                                            },
                                            ],
                                "score_mode":"sum"
                                }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: What error Do you get? There are some json format errors in above query.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RVkbaB5V This error